# php/ jquery simple log in system

Tags: php, jquery, forms, session, authentication

I am trying to create a single page app. After a successful login, a success page is displayed (login_success.php) with a link to logout. When you click the logout link, I want it to empty the "main" div, and insert logout.php (a "you have been logged out" page) into the "main" div. However, when I click the logout link, nothing happens.
js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logoutlinkdiv a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#main").empty();
        $("#main").load("templates/logout.php");
        alert("working");
   });
});
```

The alert never gets executed...

templates/login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] === null){
header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Login Successful</h1>
<h2>Username: <? echo $_SESSION['username']?></h2>
<div id="logoutlinkdiv">
<a href = "#">Log out</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>it IT</title>
<script src="reqscripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <p>Username:<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></p>
    <p>Password:<input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=? and password=?");
$sql->bind_param('ss',$myusername,$mypassword);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();//apply to prepare statement
$numRows = $sql->num_rows;

if($numRows === 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your `#main` wrap also you need to pass the event to the function `.click(function(event) {`

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè the #main wrap is there - just forgot to include it - made the change u suggested (as suggested below)...and nothing happens still

Comment: just post the code that directly applies to the problem. 
If you're able to login, then the database information is not necessary, neither index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...it turns out my application.js script wasn't being run upon login - I had to add it to the login_success.php html head. Does anyone know why though?

I change this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] === null){
header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Login Successful</h1>
<h2>Username: <? echo $_SESSION['username']?></h2>
<div id="logoutlinkdiv" > <!--onclick='swap()'> -->
    <a href = "#" >Log out</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

to this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] === null){
header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>

<html>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Login Successful</h1>
<h2>Username: <? echo $_SESSION['username']?></h2>
<div id="logoutlinkdiv" > <!--onclick='swap()'> -->
    <a href = "#" >Log out</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why I have to load the script on this page? I am trying to create a single page app...so I don't want to have to be reloading scripts all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Add event inside `function(event)`.Otherwise the default href="#" will be executed.

```
  $("#logoutlinkdiv a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    $("#main").load("templates/logout.php", function() {
        alert("working");
 });
```

Make sure that the path to your file is correct

Answer (score 0):

It's because login_success.php is a seperate static page so you need your jQuery file in there upon redirect.